# Method for adding Objects into a fixed collection(Array) in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have made an inheritance hierarchy with one super-class called Employe and two subclasses called Lecturer and Assistant. In addition to this I made a class called Subject which has an array of employees.

What I want to do here is create a method for adding Employe objects into the array.
I made the same one that works for ArrayList, but it didn't seem to work for Arrays.

If it is possible, how can I create a method for doing the same thing with arrays?

```
public class Subject {

    private String subjectcode;
    private Employe[] employees;

    public Subject(String subjectcode) {
        this.subjectcode = subjectcode;
        Employe[] employees = new Employe[5];
    }

    public void setSubjectcode(String code) {
        this.subjectcode = code;
    }

    public String getSubjectcode() {
        return this.subjectcode;
    }

    public boolean addStaff(Employe employe) {
        if (employe instanceof Lecturer || employe instanceof Assistant) {
            this.employees.add(employe);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know what happens here: `Employe[] employees = new Employe[5];`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this with an array rather than an `ArrayList`? Are you sure you'll always need just 5 employees? Why are you checking whether the employee is a `Lecturer` or an `Assistant`?

Comment: I know it would be easier to use an ArrayList, but I was wondering if it was possible to do this with an Array instead. If its not then I'll just have to use the array list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an ArrayList :

```
public class Subject
{   
    private String subjectcode;
    private final List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public Subject(String subjectcode){
        this.subjectcode = subjectcode;
}

public boolean addStaff(Employe employe){
        return this.employees.add(employe);
 }
```

Or if you still want to use an array :

```
public boolean addStaff(Employe employe){
        List<Employee> tempList = Arrays.asList(this.employees);
    boolean added = tempList.add(employe);
    this.employees = tempList.toArray(this.employees);
    return added;
 }
```

Comment: I think he said he made one that works with ArrayList, and he wants to implement it using array for some reason?

Comment: Sorry, i misread. Anyway, if the reason is to use the array somewhere else, you can do this.employees.toArray()

Comment: Added another solution that doen't change the type of this.employees

Comment: The approach that "still uses an array" is broken; it does not work when you add the 6-th employee, as the `tempList.toArray(..)` call has no effect when the list contains more than 5 elements. From the Java doc of `Collection.toArray`: ***If the collection fits** in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, **a new array is allocated** with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this collection.* This new array is returned by the toArray method, but since you don't assign the return value, it disappears into thin air.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays cannot grow or shrink dynamically by themselves as `ArrayList`s do, that's why the don't have `add()` method — it'd stop working after array instance is full.

What you have with arrays are, essentially, a `get(index)` and `set(index, value)`, so when you know that you will have at maximum `N` employees, `Subject` may look like this:

```
public class Subject {   

    private static final int N = 5;
    private String subjectcode;
    private Employe[] employees = new Employe[N];
    private int size = 0;

    public Subject(String subjectcode){
        this.subjectcode = subjectcode;
    }

    public void setSubjectcode(String code){
        this.subjectcode = code;
    }

    public String getSubjectcode(){
        return this.subjectcode;
    }

    public boolean addStaff(Employe employe){
        if (size == employees.length) {
          // cannot add when is full
          return false;
        }

        if(employe instanceof Lecturer || employe instanceof Assistant){
            this.employees[size++] = employe;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you don't know how many employees Subject may have even at a time when `Subject` is created (if you'd know it, you may pass `N` as a constructor argument), you'd have to implement method for growing internal array and call it whenever new employe is added, which may look like this:

```
private void ensureCapacity(int n) {
    int oldCapacity = employees.length;
    if (oldCapacity >= n) {
        // there's nothing to do
        return;
    }

    // grow at least in half, to minimize copying data on each add
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - n < 0)
        newCapacity = n;
    employees = Arrays.copyOf(employees, newCapacity);
}

public boolean addStaff(Employe employe) {
    ensureCapacity(size + 1);
    if (employe instanceof Lecturer || employe instanceof Assistant) {
       this.employees[size++] = employe;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For better example of growing arrays see [default implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/jdk/file/0c36d062cb0f/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l211) of `ArrayList`'s `ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)` in JDK.

But again, this growing-shrinking stuff is just reimplementing what is done already in `ArrayList` for you.

Comment: Have you tested your code? I smell a strong scent of a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Tom, yes, sorry, i've messed up while copying code from IDE and formatting it here. Now it should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In case of Java arrays, unlike ArrayList you do not have add method. So, you cannot add like it. Array operates as below:

```
        String[] employees = new String[5];
        employees[0] = "ad";
```

So, array needs index based approach, where you specify that at index 0 put this element, at index 1 put this element, and so on .... `employees[0] = "as";`

In your case, why you need to use array? I think ArrayList fits best, as per information you have provided.