# Properly defining collection in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

While reading collections in java and browsing some of the questions on stackoverflow, I came across this question:

[Method for adding Objects into a fixed collection(Array) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692091/method-for-adding-objects-into-a-fixed-collectionarray-in-java)

Here an Array has been referred to as fixed collection. Conceptually, is it legitimate to call an Array a 'fixed collection' or is it a self-contradicting phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection framework is basically a framework to store and retrieve the collection of java objects efficiently.

A very good link about overview of data structure is [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/collections/index.html)

As per this link

There are fourteen collection interfaces. The most basic interface is Collection. These interfaces extend Collection: Set, List, SortedSet, NavigableSet, Queue, Deque, 
BlockingQueue and BlockingDeque. 
The other collection interfaces, Map, SortedMap, NavigableMap, ConcurrentMap and ConcurrentNavigableMap do not extend Collection, as they represent mappings 
rather than true collections. However, these interfaces contain collection-view operations, which allow them to be manipulated as collections.

Now coming back to array its not part of collection framework  but logically its collection as it can store collection of objects. Even if you develop your custom class that can store bunch of objects you can logically call it collection object.

Answer (score 2):

An array is a collection if you define a collection as a container of elements.

Of course an array does not implement the Collection interface, but calling `Arrays.asList(arr)` on an array actually gives you a fixed size List view of that array, so you can say an array is almost equivalent to a fixed length random access List (A List is a Collection).